# What are the WebRTC samples at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ supposed to do?

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to work with the WebRTC samples from https://webrtc.github.io/samples/.

IIUC, these should be quite up to date and original minimal samples that will help to understand the technology.

So I am looking for example at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/
 which is supposed to be Peer Connection Demo.

Despite this is supposed to be *Peer* connection demo, all it does is to show me my own camera on one machine. Even if I start it on two machines, I see my own camera picture on each one.

If I read the code, I can find hints that this is supposed to make a connection between two machines, yet I fail to understand how. Nowhere on the site it is asking for a peer name, room name or anything which would identify the other party to call.

Am I missing anything here.

I know there are plenty of other WebRTC conference solutions out there on the web for demo purposes, but they all are so much more complex. I am looking for a simple 1:1 demo with source which will allow be to embrace the concept.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/akoidan/pychat  and https://github.com/akoidan/pychat/tree/master/fe/src/webrtc there're sample with webrtc you can run and debug in docker in single command `docker run -p 443:443 deathangel908/pychat-test` also you can test in at https://pychat.org in 2 windows making a call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the companion project [apprtc](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc) or steps 7 and 8 of the [WebRTC codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#6)

Having a "peer" requires an enormous amount of effort such as running a signaling server. The samples project only aims to demonstrate how to use APIs and does avoid the signaling topic by calling the API functions on another object in the same page.

Comment: I was guessing that; just wanted to double-check. They should possibly make it a bit more clear on the page.

Comment: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ mentions apprtc, the readme does not however. Updated the answer to include the webrtc codelab (which is not mentioned at all for reasons I don't understand)

Answer (score -1):

I changed the demo code myself on: http://wx.qibu.net.cn/home/demo, using signalR for websocket. you can run it between different PC
The demo code should be separate and use stun and turn servers if necessary

Comment: use firefox if you want to run my demo page. chrome need https

Comment: ... and could you maybe explain a bit how to use it? I found by chance http://wx.qibu.net.cn/home/ (without the demo) which is something different but somehow works, yet I am not entirely shure how.

Comment: peer to peer video chat demo is:http://wx.qibu.net.cn/home/demo
yes it is worked very well.steps following:1.open demo page in firefox on first PC.2.click start button.3. click enter button.4.open demo page in firefox on another PC.5.click start button at second PC too.6. click enter button at second PC too.7.back to the first PC's demo page.8.click call button.9.back to the second PC's demo page.10.click answer button.11.now you can see the remote stream show

Comment: Sorry, no luck. IIUC, I will press Start, then Enter on PC1; then I press Start and Enter on PC2, then I press "Call" on PC1 and "Answer on PC2". I do that but on both PCs I see myself and have a local audio loop. Sorry.

Comment: you can view source on chrome, copy to your IDE, then debug it

Comment: you should attention with your NAT type,

Comment: You are right about NAT. I tried that in a different network and now it works. Many thanks!